# Node.js "passport-google-oauth2" delivers "failed to fetch user profile" error in Express application

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth

While developing the last example of a [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)'s introductory [book](https://pragprog.com/book/jwnode/node-js-the-right-way) (an [express.js](/questions/tagged/express.js) application using authentication strategy by Google OpenID), after replacing the `passport-google` package *(which got obsolete on April 20th, 2015)* with `passport-google-oauth2` package (authentication strategy by Google OAuth 2.0) and having followed the indications at [its documentation's page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth2) and an [example here](https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2/blob/master/example/app.js); I got the below error after selecting my Google+ account, which was thrown by the `oath2.js` module, concretely calling `this._oauth2.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me",...)` within `userProfile(accessToken, done)` method. The related source code and module dependencies are below.

What could be the root of the problem?

The concrete error is:

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at <...>\web-app\b4\node_modules\passport-google-oauth2\lib\oauth2.js:92:28
    at passBackControl (<...>\web-app\b4\node_modules\passport-google-oauth2\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:124:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (<...>\web-app\b4\node_modules\passport-google-oauth2\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:143:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

The related application's code is:

```js
  passport = require('passport'),
  //...
  GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth2').Strategy; // #passport-google-oauth2
  //...
  /***** #passport-google-oauth2 vv *****/
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "a_specific_value",
    clientSecret: "another_specific_value",
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback:true
  },
  function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      profile.identifier=profile.id;
      return done(null, profile);
  }
  ));
  /***** #passport-google-oauth2 ^^ *****/
  //...
  /*****  #passport-google-oauth2 vv    *****/
  app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/',scope:
    [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']})
  );
  app.get( '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate( 'google', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/'
  }));
  /*****  #passport-google-oauth2 ^^    *****/
```

The application has the following dependencies:

```
b4@0.0.1
├─┬ connect-redis@1.4.7
│ ├─┬ debug@2.1.3
│ │ └── ms@0.7.0
│ └── redis@0.10.3
├─┬ cookie-parser@1.3.4
│ ├── cookie@0.1.2
│ └── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├─┬ express@3.3.8
│ ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
│ ├─┬ commander@1.2.0
│ │ └── keypress@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ connect@2.8.8
│ │ ├── bytes@0.2.0
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.14
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ │ ├── qs@0.6.5
│ │ └── uid2@0.0.2
│ ├── cookie@0.1.0
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ debug@2.1.3
│ │ └── ms@0.7.0
│ ├── fresh@0.2.0
│ ├── methods@0.0.1
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
│ └─┬ send@0.1.4
│   └── mime@1.2.11
├─┬ express-session@1.11.1
│ ├── cookie@0.1.2
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
│ ├── crc@3.2.1
│ ├─┬ debug@2.1.3
│ │ └── ms@0.7.0
│ ├── depd@1.0.1
│ ├── on-headers@1.0.0
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.0
│ ├─┬ uid-safe@1.1.0
│ │ ├── base64-url@1.2.1
│ │ └── native-or-bluebird@1.1.2
│ └── utils-merge@1.0.0
├─┬ morgan@1.5.2
│ ├── basic-auth@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ debug@2.1.3
│ │ └── ms@0.7.0
│ ├── depd@1.0.1
│ └─┬ on-finished@2.2.0
│   └── ee-first@1.1.0
├─┬ npmlog@0.0.4
│ └── ansi@0.1.2
├─┬ passport@0.2.1
│ ├── passport-strategy@1.0.0
│ └── pause@0.0.1
├─┬ passport-google-oauth2@0.1.6
│ └─┬ passport-oauth2@1.1.2
│   ├── oauth@0.9.12
│   ├── passport-strategy@1.0.0
│   └── uid2@0.0.3
├── q@0.9.7
├── redis@0.8.6
└─┬ request@2.27.0
  ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
  ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
  ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
  ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
  │ ├── async@0.9.0
  │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7
  │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
  ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
  │ ├── boom@0.4.2
  │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
  │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
  │ └── sntp@0.2.4
  ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.1
  │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
  │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.5
  │ └── ctype@0.5.3
  ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
  ├── mime@1.2.11
  ├── node-uuid@1.4.3
  ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
  ├── qs@0.6.6
  └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I just fortunately found a similar issue at
[jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/issues/46), which gave me the idea **to go to the [Google's project console](https://console.developers.google.com) and simply enable the `Google+ API`**, which was "turned off" (oh me!!, naive developer of his first application based on Google+). That was the root of the problem. I tried again and the `oauth2` started receiving profiles correctly.

Comment: I also had the deprecated scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` changed to `profile` and `email` respectively.

Comment: wow thanks spent so much time on this. they really should return some kind of error! for me callback would hung

Comment: Great answer. "Naive developer of his first application based on Google+" - :)

Comment: In my case, I had turned it on, but I just needed to wait a few minutes for it to propagate across Google servers

Comment: Wow - so weird that my auth worked without this API enabled, but I just had an annoying error every now and again

Answer (score 7):

The `scope` you are using is deprecated now :

```
passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/',scope:
  [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']})
);
```

Instead, we must use this one:

```
passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/',scope:
  ['email']
}));
```

You can also get the `profile scope`:

```
passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/',scope:
  [ 'email', 'profile' ]
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Google OAuth 2.0 Playground and in my case the reason for this error was that my token has simply expired. Refreshing it in Playground resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same error and I solved it doing this:

In package.json, change "passport" value to "^0.4.0" and "passport-google-oauth" to "^2.0.0". Run "npm install" again.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, the root cause of the issue in my case was that I initially used

```
userProfileURL:"https://googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo" (WRONG)
```

instead of using

```
userProfileURL:"https://**www**.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Tg1.png)

Comment: The solution here is correct!!! thank you for saving me.

Answer (score 0):

When I change my package from `passport-google-oauth` to `passport-google-oauth20`, everything start to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also thrown when logging in to an unpublished OAuth app with a user which is not in the `Test Users` list (under `OAuth consent screen` in [Google's project console](https://console.developers.google.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error `"Failed to fetch user profile"` was caused by a bug in the grand-parent library `node-oauth`. Specifically, it was a double callback handling.

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/issues/87

These libraries `passport-google-oauth2`, `node-oauth` are very old and not maintained well. And I didn't want to play with my own forks on GitHub. I quickly fixed it with a `package patch` approach.

https://dev.to/zhnedyalkow/the-easiest-way-to-patch-your-npm-package-4ece

How I applied a patch for the `node-oauth` library with `patch-package`:

1. Install `patch-package` library.
2. Patch `node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js` with the code:

```
  request.on('error', function(e) {
    // `www.googleapis.com` does `ECONNRESET` just after data is received in `passBackControl`
    // this prevents the callback from being called twice, first in passBackControl and second time in here
    // see also NodeJS Stream documentation: "The 'error' event may be emitted by a Readable implementation at any time"
    if(!callbackCalled) {
      callbackCalled= true;
      callback(e);
    }
  });
```

3. Run `npx patch-package node-oauth`.
4. Commit the patch file to my git repository.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue !
Solution: Inside of
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
clientID: "a_specific_value",
clientSecret: "another_specific_value",
callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback",
passReqToCallback:true,
*********************************
},

On the stared line add this link "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
Final code will be as shown below
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
clientSecret:.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
passReqToCallback:true,
userProfileURL:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
},
This hope solves the problem !